Connect SQL Without Using NTLM
Trying to connect to SQL Server without using NTLM. The instance services are using a gMSA account.
$instance = "SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL\INSTANCE"
$database = "DATABASE"
$connectionString = "Server = $instance; Database = $database; Integrated Security = $TRUE;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

I don't know how to use any other method other than integrated security.
User ID and password doesn't seem to work, I think that's for SQL Server logins, which are disabled.
Here is the full function, for reference, which is my method versus Invoke-SQLCMD
function Execute-SQL($query, [switch]$read, [switch]$write){
$instance                    = "SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL\INSTANCE"
$database                    = "DATABASE"
$connectionString            = "Server = $instance; Database = $database; Integrated Security = $TRUE;"
$connection                  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$cmd                         = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.Connection              = $connection
$cmd.CommandText             = $query
$cmd.CommandTimeout          = 0
if($write){
    try{
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    }catch{
        Write-Host $Error[0] -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        Write-Host $cmd.CommandText -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    }
}elseif($read){
    try{
        $output                = ""
        $adapter               = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        $adapter.SelectCommand = $cmd
        $DataSet               = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $adapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
        $output                = $DataSet.Tables[0] | ?{$_}
        $connection.Close()
        return $output
    }catch{
        Write-Host $Error[0] -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        Write-Host $query -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    }
}else{
    Write-Host "READ/WRITE NOT SPECIFIED" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
}
$connection.Close()

}

Which dbms are you trying to connect to? (This isn't really about the SQL language.)

Sorry, no it's not about TSQL, but I do need to connect to the server. I have a physical server hosting SQL instances and security is on my back about using NTLM. I transferred all services to a gMSA account, but it seems the connections are still using NTLM.

You mean MS SQL Server, a dbms supporting the SQL language. Obvious for the SQL Server guys, confusing for the rest of the dbms world.

Did you try reading any docs about gMSA before "transferring all services"?

Where aren't you using Invoke-SQLCMD cmdlet?  To check error use SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.  The login window of SSMS should say Windows Credentials which is equivalent to "Integrated Security = $TRUE".  There are two types of Credentials 1) SQL Server 2) Windows Credentials.  What error are you getting?

I think you need to look over: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/using-kerberos-with-sql-server, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#creating-a-kerberos-configuration-file.... Your connection is likely falling back to NTLM based on it not being able to negotiate Kerberos.

So dig into the guts of those, make some test connections, run the DMV queries at SQL level and try to work out what you need to ensure Kerberos is used for authentication. These should be coming from domain joined or trusted domain connections though. If you are connecting from other non-trusted domains, please disclose that detail if hopping between non-trusted domains or from non-domain-joined client to domain SQL Server instance, both non-domain-joined, etc. Full detail of your environments could be helpful. What version of SQL Server, what Windows client version running PowerShell, etc.

Might also look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/configure-kerberos-delegation-group-managed-service-accounts.  Run this on your domain controllers in PowerShell setspn -Q */* | % {If($_ -match 'sql') {$_}} and confirm you see what you expect. Replace 'sql' with 'SERVER'  in the match block instead to confirm what you see there. Run without if to see all.

@jdweng - No need to run Invoke-SQLCMD, the way I do it works, and has worked for years.

@siggemannen - No, I know nothing about security stuff, but someone is helping me on Thursday (tomorrow) who has security background. Seems to be a need for an SPN, which I am trying to set up, but to no avail. I think tomorrow the ISO guy will be able to help with this.

It will only work if you have Net Library installed (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection).  Powershell automatically comes with windows so no installation is needed with Invoke-SQLCMD when PS is installed.  Even with Net installed the SQLClient only exists when SQL Server is installed (or one of its components).

You need to find out using SSMS what Group/User is being used to connect to the server.  Your issue is the Group/User isn't allows access to the database (check log files).  Either you have to use a different account or modify the server/database access to allow the group to access the database.

@jdweng - Invoke-SQLCMD doesn't work, but I am checking it out and it seems this does not have nearly the options for the way I am doing it. Seems this method would default to NTLM. I've updated the original post to include the full function that I use. Again, no benefit to using Invoke-SQLCMD over my method.

Your real issue is the User/Group that is accessing the server/database.  Check the log file to see what account is being used when PS is connecting to the database.  Invoke-SQLCMD can do anything the SQLClient can do since SQLClient is being called from Invoke-SQLCMD.  PS is written in Net and SQLClient is a Net Library.

Invoke-SQLCMD and SQLClient take the same connection string (and command).  So what you are doing will work with Invoke-SQLCMD.

@jdweng - I guess I use SQLClient because I also code in C# so it's just more familiar to me.

@jdweng - There is no issue connecting to the database, the issue is that it is using NTLM despite having a gMSA account running SQL services and an SPN configured. I guess it's supposed to say Kerberos or something, and not NTLM.

@jdweng - I use this query to gather authentication methods:
SELECT  s.session_id,
s.HOST_NAME,
s.login_name,
c.connect_time,
s.login_time,
c.protocol_type,
c.auth_scheme,
s.program_name
FROM  sys.dm_exec_sessions s
JOIN  sys.dm_exec_connections c
ON   s.session_id = c.session_id
ORDER BY s.HOST_NAME, s.login_name

You are using a different account and need to change the permission of the SQL Server (or the database) to allow the account access.  You need to be a SQL Admin to make the change.  Usually the SQL Admin is the person who installed the SQL Server unless they customized the installation to use a different account for the Admin.  I had similar issue a few years back. I had to get windows Admin and then delete the SQL Server.  Then reinstall SQL Server giving me the SQL Server Admin. You need to look at the SQL Server log files to help determine what access rules need to change on the SQL Server.

Authentication method would give SQL Credentials, Windows Credentials, or OAUTH2 Credentials.  You do not want to change the type of credentials, only the account(s) that have access to the Server/Database.

@jdweng - I worked with an ISO guy today and he said that basically we disable NTLM on the SQL server (via GPO) and connections should default to Kerberos. This did not work, and we're setting up a call with a DBA from production that should know how to set this up correctly. I'll post the answer once we get all this working.

First get SSMS working.  Then check the log files.  The SSMS connection should work same as Powershell Connection since the connection string is the same.  Is the ISO guy a SQL Server expert?

@jdweng - No, the ISO guy is not a SQL expert. That's why we're setting up a call with a production side DBA.

I had issue with changing permissions on a local installation of SQL Server.  Had 4 Admins (SQL and Windows) working the issue for weeks.  Finally they gave me Local Admin and told me to uninstall SSQL and reinstall so I would have correct permissions.  Then I had to change Server/Database permission to allow a group of users access to the Database.  I used the log files to help solve all the issue.  I kept on checking the errors message and group/user that was trying to connect remotely using SQL client.  I learned a lot from solving issue.

@jdweng - this isn't a permissions issue, I can connect without issue. The problem is that it keeps using NTLM, so we're trying to figure out how to stop that. When we disabled all NTLM, however, all connections are then rejected.

The SQL Server has both Access Rights to the Server and Access rights to each database on the server.  The Group Account will be different if you switch from NTML to gMSA Credential.  So the solution is to add access to the database for gMSA Group.  Why do you need to disable NTLM.  Instead enable gMSA.  Is the glass half full or half empty?

@jdweng - The transition away from NTLM is due to our security team. We had a breach back in November last year, and they are tightening everything up. Not sure how to enable gMSA, but I have a meeting tomorrow with the DBA, so I am sure they can solve this issue. I'd like to add the gMSA perms to the DBs, but I am going to wait until tomorrow before I make any changes that need to be undone. I'll let you know how it goes after the meeting. Thanks for keeping up with this chat. :)

Sound like you can connect to Server, but not to a database in the Server.  You need to change the Access rights to the database using SSMS.

Here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/using-kerberosmngr-sqlserver, this will get you further too. You're welcome <::;;::;;::;;::;;::::::::{[|||||||]}o

@jdweng - We figured it out. We had to specify a port for each instance. The port could not be something that was being used by Windows Server. Once we did that, we had to add the instance name and the port to the SPN list. After that, all of my connections worked with NTLM disabled.

We figured it out. We had to specify a port for each instance. The port could not be something that was being used by Windows Server. Once we did that, we had to add the instance name and the port to the SPN list. After that, all of my connections worked with NTLM disabled. Had to restart SQL services for each instance for the ports to replicate. Had to use static ports, not dynamic - which seems to default to 1433.
The Kerberos Configuration Manager (download) was a fantastic tool during troubleshooting. It would show the instances and what SPNs were required for each, and whether or not that SPN was entered.

Your system may of blocked the standard 1433 port (or another app was using 1433).  Unblocking 1433 may of solved issue.

@jdweng This had nothing to do with the 1433 port. The issue is that instances all need their own distinct ports, and on top of that, you MUST have SPN records for the account running the services.

You can use same port number for more than one instance.  You have to properly specify the instance for it to work.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112916/sql-server-remote-connection-to-2nd-instance-impossible  I think you need to use servername\instance instead of .\instance.
